# Riemann integrable?

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

Consider the function: $f:[0,\frac{1}{2\pi}]\to\mathbb{R}:f(x):=x\cos(1/x)$

In general, every continuous function on a compact interval is Riemann integrable.
However, for the tagged partitions:
$$x_0:=0,x_1:=\frac{1}{2\pi N},\ldots,x_N:=\frac{1}{2\pi},t_0:=0,t_1:=\frac{1}{2\pi N},\ldots,t_{N-1}:=\frac{1}{4\pi}$$
the Riemann sums diverge:
$$\sum_i f(t_i)(x_{i+1}-x_i)=\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{1}{k}\to\infty$$

How can this happen?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How is $\;\pi\;$ a partition of $\;[0,1]\;$ ??

Comment: How can this happen while the theorem states that any Riemann sums converge?

Comment: The partition is meant as $[0,\frac{1}{2\pi N}),\ldots,[\frac{1}{2\pi},1]$.

Comment: Are you "jumping" between $\;\frac1{2\pi}\cong 0.159\;$ and all the way to $\;1\;$ ? That's not a valid partition as in the limit (Riemann Integralwise) partitions must both tend to infinite partition points **and at the same time** the mesh of the partition (i.e., the maximum of all the subintervals' lengths) must go **to zero** !

Comment: I corrected that by restriction to the interval $[0,\frac{1}{2\pi}]$.

Comment: What do you mean by gap? The definition of Riemann sums is step functions which consist by definition of steps...

Comment: How did you obtain $\sum_{k=1}^N (1/k)$? This can't be right. Any Riemann sum must be less than ${1\over 2\pi}\cdot \max\limits_{x\in [0,1/2\pi]} f(x)$. (This is beside the point, though; your sums are not guaranteed to converge to the value of the integral.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function $\;x\cos\frac1x\;$ is continuous and thus bounded at the unit integral (even at zero if we define its value as zero there) and thus Riemann integrable there.

The **actual** limit of Riemann Sums is

$$\lim_{\begin{cases}n\to\infty\\||\Delta_x||\to 0\end{cases}}\sum_{i=1}^nf(c_i)\left(x_i-x_{i-1}\right)\;,\;\;\text{with}\;\;||\Delta_x||:=\max_i||x_i-x_{i-1}||$$

and thus your proposed partitions are illegal.

Comment: What do you mean by illegal?

Comment: Read my answer about what have to fulfill partitions when doing Riemann Sums: if you **always** end the partitions in the subinterval $\;\left[\frac1{2\pi}\;,\;\;1\right]\;$ then the lengths of the subintervals of the partitions in the limit do *not* go to zero, as required.

Comment: Now it does but the problem is still there...

Comment: No, it doesn't: you still stop the last subinterval at $\;\frac1{2\pi}\;$ ...! To put weird numbers $\;1,2,..\;$ to the right of $\;\pi\;$ there doesn't change that...unless you mean something I can't understand.

Comment: I guess I don't understand your point about gaps...

Comment: Read **carefully** the definition of"Riemann *Integrable"", in particular of the condition the partitions **must** fulfill when passing to the limit, @Freeze_S

Comment: For example, read here @Freeze_S : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannSum.html  In particular, read the last two lines!

Comment: Yes the mesh size has to go to zero. But it does that in my case...

Comment: No, it doesn't @Freeze_S : as you said, it ends on $\;[1/2\pi\,,\,1]\;$ in any case...

Comment: Oh, I see you edited your question...and now it gets worse! First partition ends in $\;[1/2\pi\,,\,1]\;$ , second partition ends in $\;[1/4\pi\,,\,1]\;$ , etc....every time the last subinterval gets bigger and bigger! I think you're missing a rather important and basic understanding of this stuff...

Comment: Oh ok yes but one can easily fix that by dividing this into getting smaller subintervalls too

Comment: @Freeze_S, no: try it and you see it won't, or if you succeed write it down and show it. Don't bother: if you understood the basic case that "continuous plus bounded = Riemann integrable", then this is a closed case.

Comment: Hmm I see your point now.